# Anyone knows Facebook chatbot sending limit?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, messenger, chatbot, rate-limiting

If a merchant needs to send Facebook messages via mobile numbers (chatbot), what is the rate limit?
This is a link on this topic but it does not talk about the actual limit:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference#errors

This is graph api rate limit:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting

Thanks!

Comment: Any answer to this ?

Comment: It can get pretty dynamic and inconclusive. I am working on something automatic to throttle the Send API according to Facebook's policy. (http://api-turtle.launchrock.com/) So hopefully that could eliminate the API Limits concern. The idea is to automatically adjust the send rate if an error is returned and overtime decrease the rate limit errors to zero.

Answer (score 9):

There are two major types of rate limits that can be encountered by your app, **application-level rate limiting and page-level rate limiting**.

At Application level limit is:
**200 calls/person/hour**
which will give you error code:**4**

At Page level limit is:
**4800 calls/person/24-hours**
which will give you error code:**32**

Great description Available Here in this [reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting).

Comment: Are you sure the same limits and description will be applicable for the Messenger platform apis as well? It has additional error codes for limits - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference#errors

Answer (score 0):

The updated documentation from Facebook clearly lists out 250 calls per second as a safe limit for the Send API.

> The Send API does not have a fixed rate limit, but you can safely send 250 requests per second.

More info here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages#limits